# How would one convey "a snowball's chance in hell" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

As a good pessimist, I frequently wish to humorously convey extremely low probabilities.  I'll often use the phrase "a snowball's chance in hell," or a variation of it, to express this:

> There's a snowball's chance in hell that my candidate gets elected
>
> There's a snowball's chance in the Sahara that my efforts accomplish anything

And so forth.  Are there any common Latin expressions used for such situations?
I'm particularly interested in phrases attested in Classical Latin.

I checked [Wikipedia's list of Latin phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(full)) but didn't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually some nice options. Some (most actually) of which are more appropriate as a reply for someone who tries to do something impossible, but I decided to list them here as well as they may be suitable (maybe with little adaptation) to some instances of using "snowball's chance in hell" for what difference is there between flying turtle and snowball in hell . All of them are listed in L&S dictionary :

| Expression | description | reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Agnum lupo eripere velle | to wish to rescue a lamb from a wolf | Plaut. Poen. 3, 5, 31 |
| Findere caelum aratro | to cleave the sky by the plough | Ov. Tr. 1, 8, 3 |
| ebur atramento candefacere | to whiten ivory with ink. | Plaut. Most. 1, 3, 102. |
| Prius undis flamma miscebitur | sooner will fire mingle with water, of any thing impossible | Poët. ap. Cic. Phil. 13, 21, 49.' |
| ex incomprehensibili parvitate arenae funis effici non possit | to make a rope of sand | (Gr. ἐξἄμμου σχοινίον πλέκειν), Col. 10 praef. § 4 fin |
| Jungentur jam grypes equis | Griffins now shall mate with mares. i.e., the impossible shall happen | Verg. E. 8, 27 |
| Imbrem in cribrum gerere | to carry rain with sieve. i.e., to attempt an impossibility | Plaut. Ps. 1, 1, 100. |
| Prius pariet locusta lucam bovem | A locust will sooner give birth to an elephant. | Enn. ap. Varr. L. L. 6, 3. |
| Mulgere hircos | to milk he-goats | Verg. E. 3, 91. |
| Pinguia corticibus sudent electra myricae | let tamarisks distil rich amber from their bark. to signify something impossible | Verg. E. 8, 54 |
| Terra feret stellas | the ground to support the stars | Ov. Tr. 1, 8, 3. |
| Testudo volat | Flying turtle | Claud. in Eutr. 1, 352. |
| Nudo detrahere vestimenta | to strip the naked (of any thing impossible) | Plaut. As. 1, 1, 79. |
| Jungere vulpes | to yoke foxes. for any absurd or impossible undertaking | Verg. E. 3, 91. |
| Vultur profert cornua | vulture to grow horns | Claud. in Eutr. 1, 352. |

Answer (score 4):

Not being specially familiar with Classical works, I would use something in the line of [VG Mt 19:24](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/vul/mat019.htm#024):

> Facilius est camelum per foramen acus transire, quam divitem intrare in regnum Dei

It has been argued that the original Greek text may have used a slightly different image, but the surviving codices and those from which St. Jerome translated seem to put it that way. This means, at least, that the image was not too foreign at some point between the writing of the Septuagint and Jerome's translation. (And certainly become [well known later](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22camel%20through%20the%20eye%20of%20a%20needle%22)).

Missing a more Classical or so-to-say *pure Latin* (as in *more confidently not influenced by Greek or Hebrew*) quote, I'd say **facilius est camelum per foramen acus transire, quam [sth]** or the inverse, **difficilius est** (e.g.) **studium meum aliquod perficere quam camelum per foramen acus transire**

Answer (score 3):

It's notoriously difficult to find a precise classical equivalent for this kind of thing — though some apt examples certainly exist (*caelum digito attingit* for 'he's over the moon' is one such).

I think you might best translate it fairly simply. The meaning/intention behind *sortem habet niviglobi Gehennae* should be pretty obvious, after all!